# repeating dataframe while changing one column value

Tags: python, dataframe, append, repeat

I have a dataframe that looks like this, Dataframe1:

| Scenario | database | LCIA | product_emiss | impact | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | X | Climate | 1 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | X | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Y | Climate | 5 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Y | Marine | 9 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Freshwater | 1 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | X | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | X | Marine | 6 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Y | Climate | 7 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Y | Marine | 8 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Climate | 0 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Freshwater | 4 |

And another one like this, Dataframe2:

| Scenario | database | LCIA | product_emiss | impact | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | W | Climate | 8 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | W | Marine | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | S | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | S | Marine | 5 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | T | Marine | 7 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | R | Marine | 2 |

I want to repeat and append the dataframe2 to dataframe1 as many times as values in dataframe1[´database´] and replace the column in dataframe2[´database´] with the values in dataframe1[´database´] for each appended dataframe2.
Is this possible in python?

I expect the outcome to look like this, Dataframe3:

| Scenario | database | LCIA | product_emiss | impact | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | X | Climate | 1 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | X | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Y | Climate | 5 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Y | Marine | 9 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei1 | Back | Z | Freshwater | 1 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | X | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | X | Marine | 6 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Y | Climate | 7 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Y | Marine | 8 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Climate | 0 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei2 | Back | Z | Freshwater | 4 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | W | Climate | 8 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | W | Marine | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | S | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | S | Marine | 5 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | T | Marine | 7 |
| 1 | ei1 | Fore | R | Marine | 2 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | W | Climate | 8 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | W | Marine | 3 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | S | Climate | 3 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | S | Marine | 5 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | T | Marine | 7 |
| 1 | ei2 | Fore | R | Marine | 2 |

Comment: What do you mean by "replacing the column database with the database name in the repeated appended one"? What is the database name? If you could provide an example of the expected output, that would be useful :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by - "repeat and append the second dataframe to the first one as many times as databases in the first" - please provide what your expected output looks like

Comment: Sorry! I just added the expected outcome :)

Comment: @TomB., I have tried to make the question more clear. Does this help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a list of dataframes from dataframe2 replacing 'ei1' by the databases in dataframe2 and then concatenate them. Then concatenate this *extended* version with dataframe1. Something like this:

```py
databases = df1.database.unique()

df2_extended = pd.concat([df2.replace('ei1',db) for db in databases],ignore_index=True)

pd.concat([df1,df2_extended],ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This code creates exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function from Pandas.

```py
    >>> df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
      lkey  value_x rkey  value_y
    0  foo        1  foo        5
    1  foo        1  foo        8
    2  foo        5  foo        5
    3  foo        5  foo        8
    4  bar        2  bar        6
    5  baz        3  baz        7
```

In your case:

```py
    df1.merge(df2, left_on='database', right_on='database')
```

Not sure if that's what you really want to do though.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think this is not working for me as I need to append the dataframe2 below the dataframe1, and if I understand correctly this does it as another column, right? Please see my edits to the question which was quite unclear. I hope it is better now. Thanks!